# Generate combinations list from values in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations, permutation

I have a list of tuples, which essentially are ranges my ith value can iterate in.
The list looks like the one below:

```
L = [(10,20),(30,40),(60,70),(90,100)]
```

These are the upper and lower bounds of these ranges and will be fixed before generating all values where the bounds are inclusive.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to generate unique combination where each value of the list lies between its tuple bounds? 14641 combinations.

```
Ex: 
[15,30,65,90] is valid
[27,33,67,99] is not valid
```

I tried using for loops by nesting them but ran into issues with runtime.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Covert the tuples to ranges and then use `itertools.product`

Comment: All the combinations or just one random one? Are the upper bounds inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Hi,
I need all the combinations and yes the bounds are inclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

combos = product(*(range(a, b+1) for a, b in L))
next(combos)
# (10, 30, 60, 90)
next(combos)
# (10, 30, 60, 91)
# ...
```

If you need them in a `list`, just unpack the iterator:

```
combos = [*product(*(range(a, b+1) for a, b in L))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to map range over the intervals.

```
from itertools import product, starmap

L = [(10, 20), (30, 40), (60, 70), (90, 100)]

Ls = [(lb, ub + 1) for lb, ub in L]
for combination in product(*starmap(range, L)):
    print(combination)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
from itertools import product

L = [(10,20),(30,40),(60,70),(90,100)]
L2 = [list(range(a, b+1)) for a,b in L]

all_products = list(itertools.product(*L2))
```

Getting random values:

```
import random
random.sample(all_products, 10)
```

output:

```
[(12, 37, 61, 98),
 (15, 35, 65, 90),
 (13, 38, 61, 98),
 (12, 37, 61, 92),
 (19, 34, 63, 91),
 (15, 37, 66, 91),
 (13, 32, 66, 98),
 (17, 31, 64, 97),
 (10, 38, 63, 99),
 (16, 34, 61, 90)]
```

Comment: I just saw the comment that the bounds are inclusive

Comment: @user2390182 this is actually weird as the initial explanation was that the total combinations yielded 10k values which matched excluded upper bound

Comment: True, the OP must have miscounted :) one of the main reasons for the exclusive upper bounds in all of programming: `length = upper - lower`!

Comment: @user2390182 I know, that's why I went for exclusion by default ;)